# Build fails on Nodejs (+ React) app deployment on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, build

I build an app to practice react with a nodejs backend. It work fine on localhost. But I needed to learn how to deploy it on Heroku. I followed Stephen Grider's Udemy course and tried to hosted it on Heroku.

But my build fails. I checked many times and ran **npm install** even. But I can't get it working.

This is my **package.json** in server

```
{
  "name": "react-movies",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm insall --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "npm": "5.7.1"
  },
  "author": "pankaja92",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "moviedb-promise": "^1.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2"
  }
}
```

And this is the build error I'm getting.

```
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 5.50 KiB | 2.75 MiB/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.9.4
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.7.1
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.9.4...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 5.7.1 (replacing 5.6.0)...
remote:        npm 5.7.1 installed
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:
remote:        > nodemon@1.17.2 postinstall /tmp/build_ac7e6ff23b1b667ae4e3970742a18cc1/node_modules/nodemon
remote:        > node -e "console.log('u001b[32mLove nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:u001b[22mu001b[39mn > u001b[96mu001b[1mhttps://opencollective.com/nodemon/donateu001b[0mn')" || exit 0
remote:
remote:        Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
remote:        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
remote:
remote:        added 319 packages from 194 contributors in 7.977s
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote:        > react-movies@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_ac7e6ff23b1b667ae4e3970742a18cc1
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm insall --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:
remote:
remote:        Usage: npm <command>
remote:
remote:        where <command> is one of:
remote:        access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, completion,
remote:        config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
remote:        edit, explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
remote:        install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
remote:        outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, profile, prune,
remote:        publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script,
remote:        s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t,
remote:        team, test, token, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar,
remote:        up, update, v, version, view, whoami
remote:
remote:        npm <command> -h     quick help on <command>
remote:        npm -l           display full usage info
remote:        npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
remote:        npm help npm     involved overview
remote:
remote:        Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
remote:        /app/.npmrc
remote:        or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
remote:        Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
remote:
remote:        npm@5.7.1 /tmp/build_ac7e6ff23b1b667ae4e3970742a18cc1/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm
remote:
remote:        Did you mean one of these?
remote:        install
remote:        uninstall
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! react-movies@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm insall --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the react-movies@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.31Mmf/_logs/2018-03-22T20_32_50_639Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to findthemovie.
remote:
```

What have I done wrong ? Why's my build is failing ?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would put this as a comment but can't yet, check a spelling error in config file 
`"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm insall --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"`

Ain't that supposed to be **install**?

Comment: How dumb I am. Thanks. I thought I might have configured something incorrectly.

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana No problem, got to love those spelling errors. Spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong with a piece of code and turns out your'e one letter off for a command spelling. Then you have the option of breaking your fingers for typing it wrong, plucking your eyeballs for not seeing it, or tossing your computer out the door in frustration. Fun times...

Comment: The probelm is that no code editor can highlight those errors...

Answer (score 1):

npm install

```
> NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm insall --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
```

should be

```
> NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I might have configured something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a typo in your code.
It should be **install** instead of **insall** :

```
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in server.js file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```